# Excel lookup / compare values

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, lookup, list

I need some help to sort out an old, bulky, crappy file.

So here is my problem.

I have an excel file like this:

[image]

and i need to sort it like this:

[image]

Keep in mind that the food type changes for each user.

Thanks,

Comment: Are the cells in the `User` column **merged** ??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a helper column to translate the merged cells to single cells, **or** translate them *manually* - which I don't recommend for *a lot* of data.

[image: Screenshot]

Use this to automatically convert the merged cells: (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740523/how-to-create-result-table-with-vlookup-from-merged-cells))

```
=IF(A2="", D1, A2)
```

After that, it is fairly simple. Just use [a multiple criteria `INDEX MATCH`](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) with this formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6, MATCH(1, ($G3 = $D$2:$D$6) * (H$2 = $B$2:$B$6), 0))
```

If you don't like the `#N/A` error thrown because no match is found, wrap the whole formula in `IFNA` function:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($C$2:$C$6, MATCH(1, ($G3 = $D$2:$D$6) * (H$2 = $B$2:$B$6), 0)), 0)
```

**Note:** The last `0` convert `#N/A` error to `0` instead.

Comment: hi, thanks for this. but i cannot get the same result when i try. where do you put this formula? which cell? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot or elaborate what went wrong? The first formula goes in D column, but you need to remove the header of the source table for this to work. The second formula goes in the content area of the content table (the conversion table)

Comment: did exactly what u said and the first part is good.
the second part returns an error. can you please tell me in which cell to put the second formula. Thanks.

Comment: @Mozie1 H3:J4 expand as needed

Comment: Hello, check this:
http://imgur.com/5YUecUT